# misuse of aggregate: COUNT()

Tags: sql, database, rstudio

I have 2 tables rozmowa and abonent. I'm trying to do this:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT A.imie, A.nazwisko, A.numer, 
COUNT(R.id_abonent_to) AS ile 
FROM abonent A LEFT JOIN 
rozmowa R ON A.id = R.id_abonent_to 
WHERE ile > 4
GROUP BY A.id, A.imie, A.nazwisko, A.numer")
```

but I get an error

> misuse of aggregate: COUNT()

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: I would guess it's because R.id_abonent_to is from a left join'd table so its values aren't necessarily 'genuine'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are confusing `WHERE` with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT A.imie, A.nazwisko, A.numer, COUNT(*) AS ile
FROM abonent A JOIN
     rozmowa R
     ON A.id = R.id_abonent_to
GROUP BY A.id, A.imie, A.nazwisko, A.numer
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4;
```

Not all databases support column aliases in `HAVING`.  If yours does, you can use `HAVING ile > 4`.

Note that a `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary because you are requiring at least 5 rows that match.  (I suppose there could be other interpretations of your query, but I'm guessing that the multiple rows being counted come from `R`.)

The `COUNT(*)` is then simplification.  The column being used for the `COUNT()` is part of the `ON`.  Your version of `COUNT()` is appropriate for a `LEFT JOIN`, but unnecessary for what you are doing.

Comment: hey, thanks for helping! this works! but can you tell me why do i have to use HAVING here instad of WHERE? and why is there COUNT (*)? Doesnt that mean something like 'count all'? (im a newbie here)